# How to use binary with enum?

Tags: java, enums, binary

I want to use binary for save parameter of one user, I have an enum:

```
public enum Test {
    TEST1, (= 00000001)
    TEST2, (= 00000010)
    TEST3, (= 00000011)
    TEST4; (= 00000100)
}
```

When the user left send their choice on database with a binary addition (example `00000001` + `00000100` = ‭`00000101‬`). But when user rejoins and tries to get `Test1` and `Test2` it doesn't work, I have tried with binary operation, without having expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don`t know what you want to do with this kind of enum but you can:

```
public enum Test {
    TEST1(0b00000001),
    TEST2(0b00000010),
    TEST3(0b00000011),
    TEST4(0b00000100);

    private final int value;

    private Test(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And you can get back value using `getValue()` method and you can change the data type of `value` as par your requirement.

If it is same as in your given code then you should use `byte`.

`0b00000001`
Start your number with `0b`.

And this is how you can assign binary value to the variable

Comment: Yes, it's that but i save a addition, and my problem is how to get the two value with one binary result ?

Comment: Addition is kind of hash function which is not reversible so from the answer you can not get the values back unless one of that two value is not available. but if answer is always unique then in that case you can check all the possible combination of addition and compare it with the answer you previously got from addition.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's possible to generate the possible combination ? Or do them manually ?

Comment: Manually is the only way